# Jetpack compose custom snackbar material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to achieve a custom snackbar in compose using material 3? I want to change the alignment of the snackbar. Also I want dynamic icon on the snackbar either on left or right side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can customize your snackbar using SnackBar composable and can change alignment using SnackbarHost alignment inside a Box if that's what you mean.

```
val snackState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(20.dp)
) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    snackState.showSnackbar("Custom Snackbar")
                }
            }) {
            Text("Show Snackbar")
        }
    }
    SnackbarHost(
        modifier=Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart),
        hostState = snackState
    ) { snackbarData: SnackbarData ->
        CustomSnackBar(
            R.drawable.baseline_swap_horiz_24,
            snackbarData.visuals.message,
            isRtl = true,
            containerColor = Color.Gray
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomSnackBar(
    @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int,
    message: String,
    isRtl: Boolean = true,
    containerColor: Color = Color.Black
) {
    Snackbar(containerColor = containerColor) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalLayoutDirection provides
                    if (isRtl) LayoutDirection.Rtl else LayoutDirection.Ltr
        ) {
            Row {

                Icon(
                    painterResource(id = drawableRes),
                    contentDescription = null
                )
                Text(message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I dynamically set the icon and also icon alignment?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically set icon? You can pass icon resource as parameter. For icon alignment i assume you mean right to left, if so you can do it with `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {Your Icon here}`

Comment: I mean in any composable when I want to showSnackbar, call like this:  `scaffoldState.showSnackbar(icon = R.drawable.icon, isLeft = true, backgroundColor: Color.Transparent)`  ...

Comment: You can customize it as in updated answer

Answer (score 12):

Validated answer does not answer the question properly because the icon is provided in a static way, not dynamic. The icon is not passed to `showSnackbar`.

You can do it by having your own `SnackbarVisuals` :

```
// Your custom visuals
// Default values are the same than SnackbarHostState.showSnackbar
data class SnackbarVisualsCustom(
    override val message: String,
    override val actionLabel: String? = null,
    override val withDismissAction: Boolean = false,
    override val duration: SnackbarDuration = if (actionLabel == null) SnackbarDuration.Short else SnackbarDuration.Indefinite
    // You can add custom things here (for you it's an icon)
    @DrawableRes val drawableRes: Int
) : SnackbarVisuals


// The way you decide how to display your custom visuals
SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState) {
    val customVisuals = it.visuals as SnackbarVisualsCustom
    Snackbar {
        // Here is your custom snackbar where you use your icon
    }
}

// To display the custom snackbar
snackbarHostStateScope.launch {
    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
        SnackbarVisualsCustom(
            message = "The message",
            drawableRes = R.drawable.your_icon_id
        )
    )
}
```